# Transposh plugin to translate Ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, wordpress, translation

I'm trying to get the `transposh plugin` to translate everytime the cart is updated dynamically. Currently, the plugin will translate and then `woocommerce` would update the cart thus the translations disappear.

I found the following code in WooCommerce's `checkout.js`:

```
    // Event for updating the checkout
    $('body').bind('update_checkout', function() {
        clearTimeout(updateTimer);
        update_checkout();
});
```

I believe this is the code (I can only find the minified version of it) for how transposh gets the translations going in `transposh.js`:

```
(function(c){function D(b,a){if(0!==c.trim(a).length){var d=function(){var b=c(this).attr("id").substr(c(this).attr("id").lastIndexOf("_")+1),a=c("#"+e+"img_"+b);c("#"+e+b).attr("data-source",1);a.removeClass("tr-icon-yellow").removeClass("tr-icon-green").addClass("tr-icon-yellow")};c("*[data-token='"+b+"'][data-hidden!='y']").html(a).each(d);c("*[data-token='"+b+"'][data-hidden='y']").attr("data-trans",a).each(d)}}function E(b,a){clearTimeout(v);h.push(b);r.push(a);D(b,a);v=setTimeout(function(){var b=
{ln0:t_jp.lang,sr0:s,action:"tp_translation",items:h.length},a;for(a=0;a<h.length;a+=1)b["tk"+a]=h[a],b["tr"+a]=r[a],t+=c("*[data-token='"+h[a]+"']").size();c.ajax({type:"POST",url:t_jp.ajaxurl,data:b,success:function(){var b=t/k*100;t_jp.progress&&c("#"+m).progressbar("value",b)}});r=[];h=[]},200)}function l(b,a){E(b,c("<div>"+c.trim(a)+"</div>").text());var d=(k-c("."+e+'[data-source=""]').size())/k*100;t_jp.progress&&c("#"+n).progressbar("value",d)}function w(b,a,d){c.ajax({url:t_jp.ajaxurl,dataType:"json",
type:"GET",data:{action:"tp_gp",tl:d,q:b},success:a})}function x(b,a){w(a,function(a){c(a.results).each(function(a){l(b[a],this)})},t_jp.lang)}function y(b,a,d){c.ajax({url:"https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2",dataType:"jsonp",data:{key:t_jp.google_key,q:b,target:d,source:t_jp.olang},traditional:!0,success:a})}function F(b,a){y(a,function(d){"undefined"!==typeof d.error?x(b,a):c(d.data.translations).each(function(a){l(b[a],this.translatedText)})},t_jp.lang)}function p(b,a,d){if(t_jp.msn_key){var f=
"[";c(b).each(function(a){f+='"'+encodeURIComponent(b[a].replace(/[\\"]/g,"\\$&").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," "))+'",'});f=f.slice(0,-1)+"]";c.ajax({url:"//api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/TranslateArray?appId="+t_jp.msn_key+"&to="+d+"&texts="+f,dataType:"jsonp",jsonp:"oncomplete",success:a})}else 1===z?setTimeout(function(){p(b,a,d)},500):(z=1,c.getScript("//www.microsofttranslator.com/ajax/v2/toolkit.ashx?loc=en&toolbar=none",function(){t_jp.msn_key=_mstConfig.appId;p(b,a,d)}))}function G(b,
a){s=2;p(a,function(a){c(a).each(function(a){l(b[a],this.TranslatedText)})},t_jp.binglang)}function A(b,a,d){c.ajax({url:"http://api.apertium.org/json/translate",data:{q:b,langpair:t_jp.olang+"|"+d,markUnknown:"no"},dataType:"jsonp",traditional:!0,success:a})}function H(b,a){s=3;A(a,function(a){200<=a.responseStatus&&300>a.responseStatus&&(void 0!==a.responseData.translatedText?l(b[0],a.responseData.translatedText):c(a.responseData).each(function(a){200===this.responseStatus&&l(b[a],this.responseData.translatedText)}))},
t_jp.lang)}function B(b,a){!t_jp.msn||"2"!==t_jp.preferred&&void 0!==t_jp.google?!t_jp.apertium||"en"!==t_jp.olang&&"es"!==t_jp.olang?t_jp.google_key?F(b,a):x(b,a):H(b,a):G(b,a)}function u(){var b=[],a=0,d=[],f=[];c("."+e+'[data-source=""]').each(function(){var e=c(this).attr("data-token"),g=c(this).attr("data-orig");void 0===g&&(g=c(this).html());1!==b[g]&&(b[g]=1,a+encodeURIComponent(g).length>I&&(B(f,d),a=0,d=[],f=[]),a+=encodeURIComponent(g).length,f.push(e),d.push(g))});B(f,d)}function C(b){"function"===
typeof c.xLazyLoader?b():(t_jp.$=c,c.getScript(t_jp.plugin_url+"/js/lazy.js",b))}function q(b){q.hit?b():(q.hit=!0,C(function(){c.fn.propAttr=c.fn.prop||c.fn.attr;c.xLazyLoader({js:t_jp.jQueryUI+"jquery-ui.min.js",css:t_jp.jQueryUI+"themes/"+t_jp.theme+"/jquery-ui.css",success:b})}))}var I=1024,k,e=t_jp.prefix,n=e+"pbar",m=n+"_s",s=1,t=0,v,h=[],r=[],z=0;t_jp.dgpt=w;t_jp.dgt=y;t_jp.dmt=p;t_jp.dat=A;t_jp.tfl=C;t_jp.tfju=q;t_jp.at=u;c(function(){t_jp.msn&&(t_jp.binglang=t_jp.lang,"zh"===t_jp.binglang?
t_jp.binglang="zh-chs":"zh-tw"===t_jp.binglang?t_jp.binglang="zh-cht":"mw"===t_jp.binglang&&(t_jp.binglang="mww"));c("."+e+"setdeflang").click(function(){c.ajax({url:t_jp.ajaxurl,data:{action:"tp_cookie"},cache:!1});c("."+e+"setdeflang").hide("slow");return!1});k=c("."+e+'[data-source=""]').size();c.ajaxSetup({cache:!0});k&&!t_jp.noauto&&(t_jp.google||t_jp.msn||t_jp.apertium)&&(t_jp.progress?q(function(){c("#"+e+"credit").css({overflow:"auto"}).append('<div style="float: left;width: 90%;height: 10px" id="'+
n+'"/><div style="margin-bottom:10px;float:left;width: 90%;height: 10px" id="'+m+'"/>');c("#"+n).progressbar({value:0});c("#"+m).progressbar({value:0});c("#"+m+" > div").css({background:"#28F828",border:"#08A908 1px solid"});u()}):u());t_jp.edit&&c.getScript(t_jp.plugin_url+"/js/transposhedit.js")})})(jQuery);
```

What should I add in the checkout.js to fire the translations everytime the cart is updated?

Let me know what other details I should provide.

EDIT: I should note that I was told that the cart is being updated via AJAX. Upon research, the plugin creator of transposh had suggested users to look at the `on_init function` in `transposh.php`

This is the `on_init function`:

```
    /**
     * Setup a buffer that will contain the contents of the html page.
     * Once processing is completed the buffer will go into the translation process.
     */
    function on_init() {
    tp_logger('init ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 4);

    // the wp_rewrite is not available earlier so we can only set the enable_permalinks here
    if (is_object($GLOBALS['wp_rewrite'])) {
    if ($GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_permalinks() && $this->options->enable_permalinks) {
    tp_logger("enabling permalinks");
    $this->enable_permalinks_rewrite = TRUE;
    }
    }

    // this is an ajax special case, currently crafted and tested on buddy press, lets hope this won't make hell break loose.
    // it basically sets language based on referred when accessing wp-load.php (which is the way bp does ajax)
    tp_logger(substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], -11), 5);
    if (substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], -11) == 'wp-load.php') {
    $this->target_language = transposh_utils::get_language_from_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $this->home_url);
    $this->attempt_json = true;
    }

    //buddypress old activity
    if (@$_POST['action'] == 'activity_get_older_updates') {
    $this->target_language = transposh_utils::get_language_from_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $this->home_url);
    $this->attempt_json = true;
    }

    tp_logger($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 5);
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wpv-ajax-pagination/') === true) {
    tp_logger('wpv pagination', 5);
    $this->target_language = transposh_utils::get_language_from_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $this->home_url);
    }

    // load translation files for transposh
    load_plugin_textdomain(TRANSPOSH_TEXT_DOMAIN, false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/langs');

    //set the callback for translating the page when it's done
    ob_start(array(&$this, "process_page"));
    }
```

Here is the function for `update_checkout()`

```
function update_checkout() {

        if (xhr) xhr.abort();

        if ( $('select#shipping_method').size() > 0 || $('input#shipping_method').size() > 0 )
            var method = $('#shipping_method').val();
        else
            var method = $('input[name=shipping_method]:checked').val();

        var payment_method  = $('#order_review input[name=payment_method]:checked').val();
        var country         = $('#billing_country').val();
        var state           = $('#billing_state').val();
        var postcode        = $('input#billing_postcode').val();
        var city            = $('input#billing_city').val();
        var address         = $('input#billing_address_1').val();
        var address_2       = $('input#billing_address_2').val();

        if ( $('#shiptobilling input').is(':checked') || $('#shiptobilling input').size() == 0 ) {
            var s_country   = country;
            var s_state     = state;
            var s_postcode  = postcode;
            var s_city      = city;
            var s_address   = address;
            var s_address_2 = address_2;
        } else {
            var s_country   = $('#shipping_country').val();
            var s_state     = $('#shipping_state').val();
            var s_postcode  = $('input#shipping_postcode').val();
            var s_city      = $('input#shipping_city').val();
            var s_address   = $('input#shipping_address_1').val();
            var s_address_2 = $('input#shipping_address_2').val();
        }

        $('#order_methods, #order_review').block({message: null, overlayCSS: {background: '#fff url(' + woocommerce_params.ajax_loader_url + ') no-repeat center', backgroundSize: '16px 16px', opacity: 0.6}});

        var data = {
            action:             'woocommerce_update_order_review',
            security:           woocommerce_params.update_order_review_nonce,
            shipping_method:    method,
            payment_method:     payment_method,
            country:            country,
            state:              state,
            postcode:           postcode,
            city:               city,
            address:            address,
            address_2:          address_2,
            s_country:          s_country,
            s_state:            s_state,
            s_postcode:         s_postcode,
            s_city:             s_city,
            s_address:          s_address,
            s_address_2:        s_address_2,
            post_data:          $('form.checkout').serialize()
        };

        xhr = $.ajax({
            type:       'POST',
            url:        woocommerce_params.ajax_url,
            data:       data,
            success:    function( response ) {
                if ( response ) {
                    var order_output = $(response);
                    $('#order_review').html(order_output.html());
                    $('body').trigger('updated_checkout');
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: checkout is different from updating cart , which event do you want to fire translation ? ,also it will be better if you provide an example.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to provide an example because I don't know what the answer is. I'm also not sure when you mean by checkout is different from updating cart, but I can tell you that when you are on the billing shipping page, the cart summary (where your total costs is located at) gets updated via AJAX whenever the user is changing their shipping location. Upon changing their shipping location, because the cart summary is updated, the translations get wiped. So ideally I'd like the translations to trigger again whenever it updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging , and because im not php expert neither wp expert , but i can tell where the issue is.

First of all you should understand what `add_action` is , it is well explained [**here**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))

If you needed to create an AJAX handler for an "add_foobar" request, you would create a hook like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_foobar', 'prefix_ajax_add_foobar' );

function prefix_ajax_add_foobar() {
    // Handle request then generate response using WP_Ajax_Response
}
```

Using the above example, any time an AJAX request is sent to WordPress, and the request's 'action' property is set to 'add_foobar', this hook will be automatically executed. For example, the following code would execute the above hook.

```
jQuery.post(
    ajaxurl, 
    {
        'action': 'add_foobar',
        'data':   'foobarid'
    }, 
    function(response){
        alert('The server responded: ' + response);
    }
);
```

so now you got how actions works , then you have to get how the transposh.php ajax part works , from the transposh.php file ( i recommend you open the file in a good text editor like sublime text ) , in line `437` :

```
//buddypress old activity
        if (@$_POST['action'] == 'activity_get_older_updates') {
            $this->target_language = transposh_utils::get_language_from_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $this->home_url);
            $this->attempt_json = true;
        }
```

this simply tells our script to fire translation when this action is called, what you have to do is customizing this line a bit so it fires upon you ajax request `(update_checkout()`).

if you check `update_checkout()` function you will find the corresponding action : `'woocommerce_update_order_review'`

**Solution:**

**1. Add you wp actions**
    add_action( 'wp_woocommerce_update_order_review', 'woocommerce_update_order_review' );
    //preferably add this to line 207 in transposh.php with other add actions.

**2. Instead of adding your own function , just modify the current buddypress example.**

```
if (@$_POST['action'] == 'activity_get_older_updates')
```

to be

```
if (@$_POST['action'] == 'activity_get_older_updates' || @$_POST['action'] == 'woocommerce_update_order_review' )
//fire translation if action is equal to buddypress activity get older updates or action is equal to woocommerce update checkout.
```

**3. this guy recommends adding following condition to line 352 in transposh.php**

```
if ($this->is_special_page($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
```

to be

```
if ($this->is_special_page($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])&& !$this->attempt_json)
```

found here : http://cl.ly/Shdn/o

I hope i had a link to your page where you are using this , but you could not provide an example , so i hope this solution will work as it was meant to be.

Comment: You got it to work without the example that you requested for and you also explained quite a bit to me. Even though I found an alternative because I was such a lost little lamb, I decided to revert my changes and go with your method because... well because it works! Thank you again for teaching and spending the time to help me.